# how to display a table after i click on a button in php

Tags: javascript, php

I have an interface where there is a button.
When I click on this button a table must be displayed.
how can i do this ?

This is the code I've done :

```
//This is the button  
 
<div class="panel-body">
                <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id ="parser" name="parser" onclick="" >Parser</button></p>
                </div>
```

```
//The table I need to display 
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="matable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>ATM</th>
                                            <th>Ligne</th>
                                            <th>Event</th>
                                            <th>Montant</th>
                                            <th>Type</th>
                                            <th>Retour trans</th>
                                            <th>Retour carte</th>
                                            <th>Carte insérée</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    <?php
                                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($res)){ 
                                    
                                    
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[5] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[6] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[8] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[9] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[10] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[11] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[12] ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php }?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Do I need to use a function in JS? or the function onclick?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: yes you need to use onclick function and it is enough to show this,you can also use JS.its your choice

Comment: @pk_ how can I use onClick , I tried to use it but it didn't work

Comment: what have you tried upto now,can you share the code so i can able to see what error is there

Comment: did you include the jquery resource link in header and footer??

Comment: @pk_ Yes I did but it didn't work

Comment: okey any error ???

Comment: Any console errors? "Didn't work" tells us nothing about the actual problem

Comment: you need to use onclick button with ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try like this sure it will work**

```
 <style>
    .hidden{
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div class="panel-body">
<p><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id ="parser" name="parser" >Parser</button></p>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover hidden" id="matable">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>#</th>
                                            <th>Date</th>
                                            <th>ATM</th>
                                            <th>Ligne</th>
                                            <th>Event</th>
                                            <th>Montant</th>
                                            <th>Type</th>
                                            <th>Retour trans</th>
                                            <th>Retour carte</th>
                                            <th>Carte insérée</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    
                                    <?php
                                    while($row=mysqli_fetch_row($res)){ 
                                    
                                    
                                        ?>
                                        <tr>
                                        <td><?php echo $row[0] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[5] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[1] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[2] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[6] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[8] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[9] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[10] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[11] ?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $row[12] ?></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javscript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/3.2.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(document).on('click', '#parser', function(){
            $("#matable").removeClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a JS function to display the table:

```
<div class="panel-body">
            <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id ="parser" name="parser" onclick="showTable()" >Parser</button></p>
            </div>
```

And then addd the script tag and following code:

```
<script>
function showTable() {
        document.getElementById("matable").style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: I did that but it didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

You can hide and show table using CSS applied using javascript

1, call `hideShowTable()` function in `onclick` button event

2, applied block hide or show CSS on click button

your final code like below

```js
function hideShowTable(){
    let toggle = document.getElementById("matable").style.display;
    if(toggle == "none"){
        document.getElementById("matable").style.display = "block";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("matable").style.display = "none";
    }

}
```

```html
<div class="panel-body">
    <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" id="parser" name="parser" onclick="hideShowTable();">Parser</button></p>
</div>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="matable" style="display:none;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>ATM</th>
            <th>Ligne</th>
            <th>Event</th>
            <th>Montant</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Retour trans</th>
            <th>Retour carte</th>
            <th>Carte insérée</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10/10/22</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10/10/22</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10/10/22</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10/10/22</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>                    
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>10/10/22</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>
            <td>XXX</td>                    
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```